# popf x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

How many bytes are popped in the instruction:

```
   popf
```

? Oracle's documentation states that the size should be specified as a word or long by appending w or l to the end of the instruction but no such letters are present in the disassembly I am viewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> POPF/POPFD pops the word or doubleword on the top of the stack and
>   stores the value in the flags register. If the operand-size attribute
>   of the instruction is 16 bits, then a word is popped and the value is
>   stored in FLAGS. If the operand-size attribute is 32 bits, then a
>   doubleword is popped and the value is stored in EFLAGS.

[Source](http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/popf.htm)

Comment: In 32 bit mode it pops a dword into flags (I'm not sure if it spills into eflags or truncates, but it's the direct analog to pushf).

Comment: @Joshua I quoted the page I linked to :)